# Is there any way to type guards a block/function with my own validation function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class to manage components, but I'm really stucked in a problem with a union type and the TypeScript type guards.

Ex.

```
namespace Validation {
  export function isString(value: any): boolean {
    return (typeof value === "string" || value instanceof String);
  };
  export function isElement(value: any): boolean {
    return (value instanceof Element);
  };
};

class Component {
  constructor(selectorOrElement: string | Element) {
    var element: Element = (Validation.isString(selectorOrElement)) ? document.querySelector(selectorOrElement) : selectorOrElement;

    if (!Validation.isElement(element)) throw new Error("element is null or not found");
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWmaT.png)

I tried to validate a union type with my own type validation, but the TypeScript doesnt let me use variable as the valid type... When I validate with JavaScript default `typeof selectorOrElement === "string"` and `element instanceof Element`this works.

Is there any kind of notation or way to use my own type validation?

Comment: Please include the code itself, not a screenshot. Screenshots are not indexed by search engines.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thx. I've added some snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the type guard `is T`:

```
function isString(value: any): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}
```